# Canvas draw an image in circular increments?

Tags: html, canvas, drawimage

I would like to draw an image in circular (or similar) increments as a progress bar, I had originally wanted to draw this with lines in canvas but I ended up being unhappy with how it looked.

This jsfiddle shows how I would like it to look at 100%, none of the bar would be drawn at 0%, the start and end points of the bar are also marked.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("test");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://i.imgur.com/Jhteqyx.png";

img.onload = function() {

  ctx.drawImage(img,
    0,
    0
  );
};


//game score and level number dont draw over or clear
ctx.font = 'bold 50px Arial';
ctx.fillText("LVL NUMBER", 45, 100);
ctx.fillText(" TOTAL SCORE", 15, 190);

//label only ignore
ctx.font = 'bold 10px Arial';
ctx.fillText("end", 57, 25);
ctx.fillText("start", 125, 25);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="test" width=700 height=700></canvas>
```

I was thinking this could be achieved using additional drawImage parameters, I'm already using this to draw a countdown timer using an image as a fill but I'm not sure how to draw in a circular manner with the added complication of ignoring the middle area?

```
 context.drawImage(img,sx,sy,swidth,sheight,x,y,width,height);
```

This may be the wrong way to approach the problem, is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a clipping path to incrementally hide/reveal your border image.

Here's pseudo-code:

```
// save the context state and beginPath
ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();

// draw your clipping path here
// The clipping path will include whatever part of the image you want visible

// set your path as a clipping path
ctx.clip();

// draw your border image
// only the clipping path portion of the border image will be visible
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

// restore the context
// this turns the clipping off
ctx.restore();


// now draw your level and score (clipping is no longer in effect)

//game score and level number dont draw over or clear
ctx.font = 'bold 50px Arial';
ctx.fillText("LVL NUMBER", 45, 100);
ctx.fillText(" TOTAL SCORE", 15, 190);

//label only ignore
ctx.font = 'bold 10px Arial';
ctx.fillText("end", 57, 25);
ctx.fillText("start", 125, 25);
```

Comment: thanks again, can a single line clip an image or does it have to be an enclosing shape? the example you gave me yesterday drawing a clipping line(?) instead a coloured line in reverse would be perfect for this task.

Comment: Nope, lines can't be clipping paths.  If you want to use my previous example for clipping, just substitute rects for lines and wedges for arcs.

Comment: thanks, giving that a go now. I don't suppose you can tell me what I'm doing wrong with these rectangles? I split it into 2 functions one for vertical and another for horizontal and keeping the y co-ordinates the same for the first and the x for the latter. http://jsfiddle.net/P2qTq/1/

Comment: For horizontal lines, alter the width.  For vertical lines, alter the height.  For corners, draw wedges--arcs with closed paths (the arcs need to extend beyond the border you're trying to clip.  If you have anything but a solid background under your border, you will need to use this clipping method rather than the "reveal with reversing line" method.